# Can verified contract source be fake?

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, etherscan

Is there an exploit in the following contract?
https://etherscan.io/address/0x4876bca6feab4243e4370bddc92f5a8364de9df9
https://www.etherchain.org/account/4876bca6feab4243e4370bddc92f5a8364de9df9

It is verified on two different sites so I would assume that they are not compromised. However, the contract is drained from another contract which seems to control it :
https://etherscan.io/address/0x22a19f091a4ea624ecf17d77c9de8e0c6fad82c1#internaltx
There is no code in the source that show such capabilities. So is the code wrong or something else ? There are multiple trap like that on the chain.

Comment: Some other example https://etherscan.io/address/0x66385555FC121D18Dc95eC3A8ECd51AB2B660dE5

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's like malware.

Answer (score 2):

How have you found this contract? there seem to be a few too many of [these questions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38198/why-does-the-contract-deployment-code-of-a-specific-contract-saves-an-address-to/38211#38211) popping up on here from brand new users (with "throwaway" usernames, for bonus legitimacy points) who seem to have found a contract that's too good to be true...

This could be a legitimate question but I don't believe in coincidence, sorry! If you'd like to explain exactly how you found this contract then I'll take a proper look at it and figure out where the scam comes from in this mildly modified version of the contract posted in the question i've added a link to.

Comment: I've browsed etherscan. The contract etherscan.io/address/0x66385555FC121D18Dc95eC3A8ECd51AB2B660dE5 is the same scam (code on the right side) than the other question. However https://etherscan.io/address/0x4876bca6feab4243e4370bddc92f5a8364de9df9 does not.

Answer (score 1):

There's no exploit. It seems like that's just the functionality. The function `GetGift` allows withdrawal of the balance of the contract. The address 0x2b122ead009e73de6d76eae0bcc5d9cc52e67f08 called the contract 0x22a19f091a4ea624ecf17d77c9de8e0c6fad82c1, which called the contract you linked to and passed the necessary pass that satisfied `if(hashPass == sha3(pass))`, so it sent its balance to msg.sender.

Comment: Is there a way to see the transaction between 0x22a19f091a4ea624ecf17d77c9de8e0c6fad82c1 and 0x4876bca6feab4243e4370bddc92f5a8364de9df9, I don't find it anywhere?

Comment: Actually I think the code is correct, the transactions between contracts are not shown anywhere in etherscan. The contract certainly called PassHasBeenSet in stealth mode. Is that possible?

Comment: Function calls from contracts don't create new transactions. If you go to the "Internal Transactions" tab on the original contract, you can click on the transaction that withdrew the Ether. It was caused by address A (0x2b122ead009e73de6d76eae0bcc5d9cc52e67f08) calling the function with the signature `0x5bd74afe` on contract B (0x22a19f091a4ea624ecf17d77c9de8e0c6fad82c1) and passing in the original contracts address+the correct pass. Contract B then called the original contract with the data that address A gave to it.